# using a Resource Variable in a Textblock

Tags: c#, variables, textbox

So I have a project where I am setting up a resource variable named TEST (Right clicking on the  project in the Solution Explorer, choosing Properties, then choosing Resources) and I want to pass those into a textbox on a WPF XAML form.  It seems to be different than if I try to use a normal variable but alas, I am befuddled.

Can anyone guide me please on how to pass the variable thru please?

Thank you.

```
I know this is not the correct method
======================================
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Bottle_1_Title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

This is also not valid and I am not seeing the intellisense to help me
<TextBlock Text="{resource.test}"
```

Comment: try this `Text="{x:Static prop:Resources.test}"`

Comment: @user3373603

The namespace prefix "prop" is not defined.
Resources is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

Comment: can anyone help?